# Upgraded Mongo from 4.4 to 5.0 now DB won't start

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

My DB runs in AWS and I upgraded to Mongo 5.0. Now I cannot even start the database because I get the the following error:

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-10-25 00:16:42 UTC; 26min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3888 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=62)
  Process: 3886 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3883 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3881 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

According to the docs status=62 means there is an incompatibility issue.

I would like to downgrade back to 4.4 but there is no clear way to do so. Mongo Docs assumes the DB is running and says to run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )`

I can't run this command since the DB won't even start.

I deleted the the 5.0 binaries but that didn't do anything. The DB version is still showing "5.0.3"

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Here is some additional output:

```
Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
mongod[3591]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
mongod[3591]: forked process: 3594
mongod[3591]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 62
mongod[3591]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
sudo[3579]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=62
systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

Ran the following command: `cat mongod.log | tail -10`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.833+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635202173:833865][3594:0x7f52128ce280], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 2, snapshot max: 2 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 441594"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.839+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795903, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reconfigure complete","attr":{"durationMillis":127}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.839+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.839+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1635202173:839582][3594:0x7f52128ce280], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 4, snapshot max: 4 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 441594"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":28}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-25T22:49:33.867+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}
```

Comment: Did you check your config file? When you install new MongoDB, then the config file if overwritten by a default file.

Comment: Did you check the log mongod file?

Comment: I added additional log output

Comment: Can you show some more, e.g. tail -30

Answer (score 1):

This solved the same problem for me.

### Remove version 5.0

##### Stop mongod service

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

##### Backup your data directory

```
cp -r /var/lib/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb_backup
```

##### Remove version 5.0 and it's data

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm /etc/mongod.conf

# Remove all mongo-org apt sources
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-*
```

### Install version 4.4

Follow the instructions here [mongodb v4.4 documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

##### Run version 4.4 server

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

##### Backup your data using mongodump

```
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/mongo-data
cd $HOME/Desktop/mongo-data

mongodump
```

### Remove version 4.4

##### Stop mongod service

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo rm /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

##### Delete data directory

```
rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

##### Remove version 4.4 and it's data

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm /etc/mongod.conf

# Remove all mongo-org apt sources
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-*
```

### Install version 5.0

Follow the instructions here [mongodb v5.0 documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

##### Run version 5.0 server

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

##### Restore your data using mongorestore

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/mongo-data

mongorestore
```

**Congratulations!** now you have your old data working on v5.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and even with a clean new installation I was unable to upgrade from **4.4** to **5.0** without getting the exit code **62** `EXIT_NEED_DOWNGRADE`. Sad, but true.

Anyway, my solution was to back up the database (*version 4.2*) using `mongodump`, completely remove MongoDB from my system and then cleanly install it again, but in the latest version (*6.0*). Then I was able to restore the database using `mongorestore` without any problems.

The backup allowed me to skip an upgrade from **4.2** to **4.4**, to **5.0** to **6.0**, without any errors.